# Unreachable code detected (but there is no error)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I did this function to display the Excel file content such as worksheet etc. 
but I got this warning saying Unreachable code detected. Can anyone tell me why? 
Thank you.

```
    if (false)
            {
                #region Error Address List
                worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[8] as Excel.Worksheet;
                range = worksheet.UsedRange;
                generateErrorEditorModel(range, "PTSR9005  HMI Address V0.9");
                #endregion
            }
```

Comment: Change to `if (true)` doesn't make any sense, if the region should be executed always then just remove the whole `if` condition

Comment: You probably wanted to check if some boolean variable is false, like `if (condition == false)`, or shorter `if (!condition)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why?

Because of the `if(false)`, the following block will never have a chance to be executed. That's why it said: *Unreachable code detected*. Means that those codes will never be reached in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to start with `true`.  but it does beg the question why have this `if` statement?

```
if (true)
{
    #region Error Address List
    worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[8] as Excel.Worksheet;
    range = worksheet.UsedRange;
    generateErrorEditorModel(range, "PTSR9005  HMI Address V0.9");
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: cause I have other condition too that make me to use if statement. I only show one of the condition. thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

For an `if` statement to be executed, the condition of expression should be `true` or to be evaluated as `true`. Here, the condition is directly `false`. If you want it to be executed, change the `false` to `true`.

Example:

```
if (true)
{
   #region Error Address List

   worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[8] as Excel.Worksheet;
   range = worksheet.UsedRange;
   generateErrorEditorModel(range, "PTSR9005  HMI Address V0.9");

   #endregion
}
```

Comment: Or, you know, just remove the if statement altogether.

Comment: That's true. I just wanted to help the asker know why it's not entering the `if`statement body.

Comment: @Psylence I have other condition too that make me need to use if statement, but thank you for your answer :)